# Why doesn't `not(foo)` raise SyntaxError?

Tags: python, syntax

In Python, boolean operators are [`and, or not`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

I didn't find anywhere in the documentation where the operators can be used as statements or functions; yet this does not throw any errors?

```
>>> not(1)
False
```

But this does

```
>>> and(1)
SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax
```

Is there something I am missing about `()` that allows that to work?

Comment: Parens are also used for grouping. You have a group of one item, not a call operation.

Comment: Close voters: why? This is certainly a real question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That works for the same reason that this works:

```
not (True and False)
```

Namely, the parens act as a grouping operator, *not* to indicate a function call.  Anywhere that an expression is legal, parens are also legal and serve to explicitly group together one entire expression, which can be used to override the precedence of other operators (as in `(x + y) * z`, which is not the same as `x + y * z` -- the latter being equivalent to `x + (y * z)`).

`and` requires two arguments, which is why `and(1)` is a syntax error -- you only specified one argument.  `(x) and (y)`, however, *is* legal.

Comment: Because `not` is a *unary* operator -- it acts on one argument, which is given to the right.  `and` is a *binary* operator, and takes two arguments, one to the left and one to the right: `(x) and (y)`.

Answer (score 3):

You get the SyntaxError with `and` because it's a binary operator, not because of the parentheses:

```
(1) and(1)
```

is legal Python syntax.

Comment: You know, sometimes its just so obvious. I am not sure how I missed this little tidbit.